# Native Library for WCF Service

Tags: wcf, native

Is there any native library/way out there that I can use to communicate with a self hosted WCF service and use Windows authentication? In other words I'm writing a native C++ client that needs to connect to the WCF service, so the're no way to use the "Add Service Reference" from VS and the proxy generated from Svcutil is managed (I can't have any managed code). FYI, I already tried WWSAPI with no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: Adding a service reference or using svcutil.exe doesn't give you a proxy?

Comment: Thank you Tim, I just edited my question. I can't add a service reference to the project because it's unmanaged C++. I can't use svcutil because I don't want any managed code that I'll then have to wrap.

Comment: Library advice is offtopic for SO. Search the web for "C++ soap client library" (assuming the WCF service is exposed on a SOAP binding like basicHttp or wsHttp) and try a few.